# Javascript Array with Double Quotes

Tags: nativescript

I'm using Nativescript Http.getString to get a list of dates from a web service.

The Web service returns a string as expected which I then want to use in a Javascript Array.

The String is "'31/08/2021','24/12/2021','25/12/2021','26/12/2021','27/12/2021','28/12/2021','29/12/2021','30/12/2021','31/12/2021','01/01/2022','01/04/2022','04/04/2022'" or similar, the dates will change over time.

But I want to have a Javascript DateArray = ['31/08/2021','24/12/2021','25/12/2021','26/12/2021','27/12/2021','28/12/2021','29/12/2021','30/12/2021','31/12/2021','01/01/2022','01/04/2022','04/04/2022'] so removing the double quotes before using in the array.

I cannot find a way to remove the double quotes and apply the result to the Javascript Array.

Comment: Split the string based on commas (,) and then convert each element into a Date object.

Comment: Are the double quotes a part of the actual text ore just a regular string presentation?
In any case, in order to remove double quotes from the start and the end of a string you can use ```str = str.replace(/"/g,"")``` or ```str[str.length-1] = ""; str[0] = ""```

Comment: The Double quotes are part of the returned string from the web service. I have tried building the string as the Array would look so ['31/08/2021','24/12/2021','25/12/2021','26/12/2021'] format, but is still returned as a String "['31/08/2021','24/12/2021','25/12/2021','26/12/2021']" from the web service which Javascript does not like for Arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I've rewritten to output JSON then parse the JSON output to a Javascript Array. Much easier to do and handle rather than a string output.